# Does javascript new Date(timestamp) return date according to client's timezone?

Tags: javascript

I have a situation when i retrieve a timestamp from the server and use the following :-

```
var x = new Date(timestamp);
```

Does x give the time as per the client's timezone ?

Comment: What it timestamp?  string? numeric milliseconds?  The visual representation is easy enough to figure out as well -- just `toString()` it; use `getTimezoneOffset()`; call `UTC()`.  Try it yourself. this one is too easy for you to test yourself.

Comment: I am using mysql current_timestamp while storing it in the database .

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to ensure that the timestamp you put in the `new Date()` constructor is in [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and in miliseconds, which is not always the case when you get the timestamp from a sever.

Next, the acutal `Date` object will just store this timestamp and provides some methods to transform it and to display it in a human readable form. Just take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date and try some things for yourself.
One thing that it definitely does is using the <s>correct</s> client timezone in the `toString()` method:

```
var x = new Date(timestamp);
console.log(x); //Sat Jun 01 2013 18:00:12 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)
                //that was the result for my timezone
```

Comment: What do you mean by uses correct timestamp in toString() method ? What has toString() got to do with timezone ?

Comment: He simply meant that the local time zone settings are used when you put a Date object into a string context (for example by using console.log as in his example, or maybe something like `"This date has the value: "+x`) – which triggers the Date objects `toString` method to be called implicitly.

Comment: Wow, I've never seen a browser writing out the timezone string. What are you using?

Comment: @Bergi I'm using Chrome but I just tried it in Firefox with the same result. What are you using?

Comment: Opera just yields `… GMT+0200` for me. Maybe I'm the odd one out :-)

Comment: Ah no, I didn't know that you meant the text inside the parentheses. Firefox doesn't print that either.

Answer (score 0):

I think it gives the time according to timezone set in the client operation system.

Comment: Depends on the input `timestamp` and the output method…